# How do I initiate a method within main activity from an onInit?

Tags: java, android

I need to know code to fix my example below to initiate a method within my activity.

**Code:**

```
 public void onInit(int status) {

     HowDoIStartThisMethodCorrectly?(); <-- because this doesn't start that method.
```

}

I need a method within my main activity to run when program starts, so I add to onCreate my onInit method, but it's not working.

Comment: You call the method. Your question lacks details anyone can use to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the code in `onCreate()` is guaranteed to run:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    PUTYOURMETHODHERE();

}
```

Or you could do:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    onInit();

} 

public void onInit() {

    HowDoIStartThisMethodCorrectly?(); <-- because this doesn't start that method.

}
```

Comment: I cant start this for some reason: public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { } } } assuming their is code inside to do whatever.... i tried method(); in onCreate..?